# How to apply data binding for separate classes?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have some troubles with understanding how to use proper binding for following binding scenario:

**Binding source:**

Dependency property called 'ItemsS' in class ViewModel.MyClass1.cs

**Binding target:**

Dependency property called 'ItemsT' in class View.MyClass2.xaml.cs

As you can see MyClass1.cs and MyClass2.xaml.cs are in different project folders.

I would highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `ItemsS` and `ItemsT` are bound to each other right?

Comment: @Sankarann: What does it mean 'bound to each other'?

Comment: @Sankarann: I want to bind them together, if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of this...

Define the `ViewModel.MyClass1` as `StaticResource` like this

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:ViewModel.MyClass1 x:Key="viewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>

ItemsT="{Binding Path=ItemsS, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}"
```

where `local` is the `xmlns`..